# DataTables cannot add row not working why

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to use [this method](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row). `html`, my table is consisting of several different `HTML` elements, they are of the type select and input. I have simplified it here to one input and one column only. My goal is to click the 'add row' button and add an exact row with all the elements to the table. But when I click the 'add row' button The number of entries gets incremented, in the console there is no error or warning, but still I do not see a new row being added to the table.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        let tbl_add_unit;
        let _jAddOrg;   //更新前
        let _jAddUpt;   //更新後
        let _colDefs_addUnit;
        let _columns_addUnit = [
            { "data": "NO", "title": "NO", "name": "NO" },
            { "data": "APPLY_DATE", "title": "適用開始年月", "name": "APPLY_DATE" },
            { "data": "PRICE", "title": "単価", "name": "PRICE" }
        ];
    
        if (tbl_add_unit != null) {
           tbl_add_unit = $('#tblAddUnit').DataTable();
           tbl_add_unit.destroy();
           $('#tblAddUnit').empty();
           tbl_add_unit = null;
        }
    
        tbl_add_unit = $('#tblAddUnit').DataTable({
        destroy: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
              url: '@Url.Action("AddPriceUnitList", "CaseYG")',
             　method: 'POST',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: {
               　　　　oilcd: row.find("td").eq(0).text(),
               　　　　sitecd: _siteCd
                      },
                     　dataSrc: function (response) {
                            var parseRows = null;
                            _jAddOrg = $.parseJSON(response.data);  //元データを保持
                            parseRows = $.parseJSON(response.data);
                            return parseRows;
                        }
                    },
               columns: _columns_addUnit,
               columnDefs: _colDefs_addUnit,
               info: false,
               deferRender: true,
               searching: false,
               lengthChange: false,
               ordering: false,
               scrollY: '30vh',
               scrollX: true,
               scrollCollapse: true,
               rowReorder: true,
               dom: '<"top"l>t<"bottom">',
               error: function (error) {
                  　　alert(error);
               }
                    
         });
                
    tbl_add_unit.row.add([　　// => cannot add
       {
           "NO": "",
           "APPLY_DATE": "",
          　"PRICE": ""
       }                
    ]).draw(false);
```